# In English, is there a suffix to indicate abundance, big size, or intensity?

Tags: suffixes

In Spanish there is a suffix, [-udo](https://dle.rae.es/-udo), that's used for "in adjectives derived from nouns, it indicates abundance, big size, or intensity of the meaning of the root."  Is there something like this in English?

Comment: I might use **-rich** to point to density: mineral-rich land, protein-rich meal, experience-rich travel.

Comment: See Wikipedia's article about [Augmentative affixes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Augmentative#English) in English; it only gives one suffix, an informal one with few citations: [*-zilla*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-zilla) (Not posting this as an answer because it's not exactly what you need)

Comment: Doesn't **-ful** do this?  Or is there a subtlety I'm missing?

Comment: Prefixes (like *over*, *mega*, *super*, *archi*, *ultra*) ) are more common for that.

Comment: Can you give an example of when you'd use it.

Comment: Here's something along those lines though not an exact match: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/-orama

Comment: @MichaelSeifert Not really, *ful* just turns a noun into an adjective. So, *beautiful* just describes something which has beauty, not something that has oodles of beauty, as it were.

Comment: Barmar makes a good point @ MichaelSeifert.

Comment: The suffix 'amundo' from the Spanish 'mundo' is the closest I can think of. 'Perfectamundo' and so on.

Comment: May we have (a lot) more detail to work on? Can you Post three or four complete sentences in Spanish with both literal and idiomatic translations in English? While you're at that, why are abundance and intensity not while  size is qualified, here as 'big'?

Comment: Could you drop the 'big' from 'big size' and more usefully, specify exactly how 'big size' translates? My suggestion is that 'big size…' will never work in English; so much not that the translation is necessarily doubtful.

You might have meant 'great size' but that would be a different thing, calling for a different translation…